# VideoJS no source specified when initialized leads to error (react)

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, video.js

I am using VideoJS with React.

I am not specifying the src of the video when VideoJS is initialized in `componentDidMount` because this video player laods source dynamically, and upon load, there is no source chosen/received. That get set later via AJAX call when users click to view specific content.

That being the case, I recieve an error upon initialization of my component in componentDidMount:

```
 componentDidMount(){
    videojs("myvideo", {}, function(){
      // this initializes the player.
      });

 }
```

After page renders, I recieved the error:

```
VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported. i {code: 4, message: "The media could not be loaded, either because the …rk failed or because the format is not supported."}
```

My video tag looks like this:

```
return(
//...other stuff here

       <video id="myvideo" className="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls  preload="auto" width="1000" height="1000">
             <source id="video-source" type="video/webm" />
        </video>)
```

As you can see no src video is specified just yet when videojs is initialized. What can I do not receive the error upon load?